# Create a like/dislike bar based on two numbers - PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have two numbers I want to try and create a like/dislike bar from. below is my PHP and HTML the HTML uses a width value to show the amount of "like" in the dislike bar. See below:

```
<div class="dislike_base">
    <div class="like" style="width: 52%"></div>
</div>
```

I am just not sure how to do the mathematical comparison of the two numbers to get the percent.

PHP:

```
$like_post_num = 13;
$hate_post_num = 10;
$total = $like_post_num + $hate_post_num

//how do I compare the above information to get the percent of 100 of likes vs dislikes.
```

Please let me know if that does not make sense?

Comment: How about? `$like_percent = $like_post_num / ($like_post_num + $hate_post_num) * 100;`

Comment: I will test the that right now. As soon as I posted seeing it on the screen I had already started to getting something close. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$total = $like_post_num + $hate_post_num;
$percent = round(($like_post_num / $total) * 100);
```

Comment: That's an interesting downvote... Care to let me know the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$like_post_num = 13;
$hate_post_num = 10;
$sum = $like_post_num + $hate_post_num;

$like_percent = round($like_post_num / $sum * 100);
$hate_percent = round($hate_post_num / $sum * 100);
?>

<div class="dislike_base">
    <div class="like" style="width: <?php echo $like_percent; ?>"px></div>
    <div class="dislike" style="width: <?php echo $hate_percent; ?>"px></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a hint: you should add a unit to your width (such as `px` or `em`); right now, your width is unit-less and therefore unused.